# My onActivityResult() is never called

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 2 Activities, Parent Activity starts Child Activity. When we are in Child Activity, the User closes it via the "Up"-Button in the menu and is returned to Parent Activity.

Essential code snippets:

**Parent (Main) Activity:**

```java
protected static final int TIMERCHOOSER_REQUEST = 1;
```

starting new Activity (called from a menu button):

```java
private void openTimerChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimerChooserActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent,TIMERCHOOSER_REQUEST);
    }
```

and for fetching the result:

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    Log.d("Main", "called onActivityResult");  //this and below is never executed
    if (requestCode == TIMERCHOOSER_REQUEST) {
        switch(resultCode) {
            case RESULT_CANCELED:
                Log.d("Main", "Intent result was canceled by TIMERCHOOSER");
            case RESULT_OK:
                //code to handle data from TIMERCHOOSER_REQUEST
                Log.d("Main", "accepted resultCode. value: "+resultCode);
                String result = data.getStringExtra("result");
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            default:
                Log.d("Main", "invalid/unhandled resultCode? value: "+resultCode);
        }
    }
    else
        Log.d("Main", "invalid/unhandled requestCode? value: "+requestCode);
}
```

**Child Activity ("TimerChooserActivity"):**

```java
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch(id) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            Log.d("TimerChooser", "finishing intent");
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("result", "Some result");
            /*if(result == "User activated textview")
                setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
            else
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED,returnIntent);*/
            setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
            finish();
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

You get back to the Parent(Maint) Activity via the home/up button in the menu / action bar. This works. But `onActivityResult()` is never called, no matter what kind of result I set.

There's no weird tag in my manifest, too. Just standard stuff:

```
android:allowBackup
android:icon
android:label
android:theme
android:name
android:parentActivityName
android:value
```

What's going on?

Comment: Are you setting the result from setResult() method when you are coming back to child activity...?

Comment: In your `android.R.id.home` case you aren't returning a value, instead you are falling through to the default case.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by coming back to child activity? I never get the result no matter how many times I go back to the child, or the main activity. The main activity never sets any results, too. My code is all pretty low-level stuff, as I am learning android. I could post the whole 2 classes, but I think that's a bit overkill.

Comment: @akodiakson. THANKS DUDE. THATS IT! It works now :)

Okay, how do I close this question now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `android.R.id.home` case you aren't returning a value, instead you are falling through to the default case